# notifyDataSetChanged() not working with GridView inside Fragment

Tags: android, gridview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a gridview inside my fragment that is populated by a BaseAdapter.

The problem is that in my adapter i have a favorite button, and when i click i want the button to change. But the logic in API is done, but my button just change when i reload page.

I tried using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but didn't work.

My getView adapter code:

```
//Implementando os clicks
    itemHolder.imgFavorito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!util.isLogado(context)) {
                ((MainActivity) context).selectDrawerItem(new LoginFragment());
            }

            try {
                SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
                produtoFavorito(new favoritarProduto().execute(pref.getString("USID", "null"), item.getId() + "").get());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            fragment.notifyAdapterChanged();
        }
    });
```

In fragment.notifyAdapterChanged(); line a just call my Fragment that i recieve in constructor of adapter, and this is the function:

```
public void notifyAdapterChanged(){
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

EDIT1: How my layout looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/35IU9.png

EDIT2: My full Adapter

public class ProdutoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<ProdutoResumido> itens;
private HomeFragment fragment;

public ProdutoAdapter(Context context, List<ProdutoResumido> itens, HomeFragment fragment) {
    //Itens do listview
    this.itens = itens;
    //Objeto responsável por pegar o Layout do item.
    //mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

public int getCount() {
    return itens.size();
}

public ProdutoResumido getItem(int position) {
    return itens.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ItemSuporte itemHolder;
    //se a view estiver nula (nunca criada), inflamos o layout nela.
    if (view == null) {
        //infla o layout para podermos pegar as views
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_produtos_fg, null);

        //cria um item de suporte para não precisarmos sempre
        //inflar as mesmas informacoes
        itemHolder = new ItemSuporte();
        itemHolder.imgProduto = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgProduto));
        itemHolder.txtPreco = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPreco));
        itemHolder.imgFavorito = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgFavorito));
        itemHolder.txtNomeProduto = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeProduto));
        itemHolder.txtEstadoProduto = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtEstadoProduto));
        itemHolder.imgLoja = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgLoja));
        itemHolder.txtNomeLoja = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeLoja));

        //define os itens na view;
        view.setTag(itemHolder);
    } else {
        //se a view já existe pega os itens.
        itemHolder = (ItemSuporte) view.getTag();
    }

    final Context context = view.getContext();

    //pega os dados da lista
    //e define os valores nos itens.
    final ProdutoResumido item = itens.get(position);
    Loja loja = new Loja();
    itemHolder.txtPreco.setText("R$ " + new DecimalFormat("#.00").format(item.getValor()));
    itemHolder.imgFavorito.setImageResource(produtoFavorito(item.getFavorito()));
    itemHolder.txtNomeProduto.setText(item.getNome());
    itemHolder.txtEstadoProduto.setText("ESTADO: " + item.getTempoUso());
    itemHolder.txtNomeLoja.setText(item.getLoja());
    try {
        if (item.getImagem() != null)
            new DownloadImageTask(itemHolder.imgProduto).execute("http://200.98.202.23/JustForMoms/" + item.getImagem());
        if (item.getLojaImg() != null)
            new DownloadImageTask(itemHolder.imgLoja).execute("http://200.98.202.23/JustForMoms/" + item.getLojaImg());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //Implementando os clicks
    itemHolder.imgFavorito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!util.isLogado(context)) {
                ((MainActivity) context).selectDrawerItem(new LoginFragment());
            }

            try {
                SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
                produtoFavorito(new favoritarProduto().execute(pref.getString("USID", "null"), item.getId() + "").get());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            fragment.notifyAdapterChanged();
        }
    });


    //retorna a view com as informações
    return view;
}

private int produtoFavorito(Boolean favorito) {
    if (favorito)
        return R.drawable.favorite;
    else
        return R.drawable.notfavorite;
}

/**
 * Classe de suporte para os itens do layout.
 */
private class ItemSuporte {

    ImageView imgProduto;
    TextView txtPreco;
    ImageView imgFavorito;
    TextView txtNomeProduto;
    TextView txtEstadoProduto;
    ImageView imgLoja;
    TextView txtNomeLoja;
}


private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}

public class favoritarProduto extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private String retorno;
    private String url;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        String usID = params[0];
        String prodID = params[1];

        url = "http://200.98.202.23/JustForMoms/Produto/FavoritarProduto/" + usID + "/" + prodID;

        webclient client = new webclient(url);
        retorno = client.getmodel();

        if (retorno != null) {
            if (retorno.equals("\"incluido\"")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }


        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

}

EDIT 3:

```
 //Implementando os clicks
    itemHolder.imgFavorito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!util.isLogado(context)) {
                ((MainActivity) context).selectDrawerItem(new LoginFragment());
            }

            try {
                SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
                itemHolder.imgFavorito.setImageResource(produtoFavorito(new favoritarProduto().execute(pref.getString("USID", "null"), item.getId() + "").get()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ProdutoAdapter.this. notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: post your full  adapter class

Comment: Two things 1> produtoFavorito method declaration shows it returns int, in your code you are calling it but not capturing its return value :o din understood your logic there 2>Why notifyAdapterChanged on fragment?? You are inside adapter right?? why calling notifyAdapterChanged on fragment? Why not simply calling this.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: 1 - Thing, it was my mistake, resolved, but the problem keeps happening.
2 - Because this.notifyDataSetChanged(); code don't accept "Cannot resolve method"

Comment: Dude your ProdutoAdapter is not extending any Adapter class like BaseAdapter or something like that :o thats why it is not accepting this.notifyDataSetChanged();  :) If possible extend your adapter to be BaseAdapter :) and then simply call this.notifyDataSetChanged(); and lemme know if issue still persists.

Comment: Of course it's extending : public class ProdutoAdapter extends BaseAdapter 


import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

Comment: Ok Sorry I din notice because the code snippet you pasted first statement is not formatted properly :) anyway I figured it out, this.notifyDataSetChanged(); is not getting detected because you are calling it inside imagebutton's onclick event. When you are inside onClick(View v) and you refer this this points to imagebutton and image button does not have method named notifyDataSetChanged :) What you can do is replace fragment.notifyAdapterChanged(); with ProdutoAdapter.this. notifyDataSetChanged(); can you please try and lemme know whats happening??

Comment: Still not updating my Gridview, just update when I re-enter on fragment

Comment: tell me one thing if I am rite you are calling favoritarProduto which makes a server call to update favorite status and when you recieve response you parse it to find whether it was success or not but where are you upating yor item with the status?? :o What I mean is in order to show bitmap you are depending on item.getFavorito() but where are you updating it?

Comment: Ohhh god!!!! Sorry a small mistake in your code dude :) You know you are calling favoritarProduto which is AsyncTask :) Did you get it now??? :P

Comment: Yeah... i get it. I'll try to do some logics to change image while my asyncTask runs :), Thank You

Comment: Bingo :D Anyway am writing answer for the same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, You are calling favoritarProduto() which in turn makes a call to server to update the favorite status :)

But you missed one simple thing :) Dude its Async call :) That means it takes time to execute the code inside doInBackground:) How can you expect the status to be updated and ready immediately as if it is synchronous call??? :)

Modify the code as shown here

```
public class favoritarProduto extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private String retorno;
    private String url;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        String usID = params[0];
        String prodID = params[1];

        url = "http://200.98.202.23/JustForMoms/Produto/FavoritarProduto/" + usID + "/" + prodID;

        webclient client = new webclient(url);
        retorno = client.getmodel();

        if (retorno != null) {
            if (retorno.equals("\"incluido\"")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }


        }

        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean response) {
           //call your produtoFavorito fro the item holder based on prodID you have received :) 
    }

}
```

Comment: Always welcome @leonardo-accorsi :) Glad I could help :)